# Преобразование к типу datetime

Tags: node.js, sql-server

Есть поле input (календарь , dateformat dd-mm-yyyy).

Значение передается через `form (method=post)` в node js и из базы mssql 2012, должен происходить поиск.

Пробовал и convert(datetime, @keydate, 105) и cast, вроде как sequelize  решает эту проблему, но тут явно есть какая-то мелочь которую я не знаю и проще исправить её.

```
router.post('/fdate', function (req, res, next) {
    reqw.input('keydate', mssql.DateTime, keydate)
        .input('keydate2', mssql.DateTime, keydate2)
        .query(" SELECT  * FROM insertsql WHERE (   [inserttime] >= (@keydate) and [inserttime] <=(@keydate2) )",
            function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send(err);
                }
                res.render('index', {
                    items: result
                });
            });
});
```

Как из Html передать значение в nodejs в формате date, datetime?

Ошибка

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Comment: MySQL или sql-server? Это не одно и то же.

Comment: @user311189 покажите в каком формате у вас в запрос попадают значения дат.

Comment: Выполните запрос 'SELECT  @keydate AS keydate" и посмотрите результат, может  все же должен быть использован какой-нибудь TYPES.DateTime, а не mysql.DateTime

Comment: @Nick Proskuryakov в этом и сама проблема, если делать только в mssql все получается. А вот когда пытаешься через форму непонятно какого формата данные и как проверить я не разобрался ещё.

Comment: @Denis Rubashkin mssql(2012)  выполнил запрос, должна быть выведена дата , но возникает ошибка. Теперь такой вопрос , как передать из html в node js значение в формате date( var keydate=new Date(), не подойдет, нужно вводить самому)?